# Why does Python add a whitespace after printing int then string?

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
num = input('Amount of numbers:')
num = int(num)
for x in range(1, num + 1):
    if x == 1:
        print('1st')
    elif x == 2:
        print('2nd')
    elif x == 3:
        print('3rd')
    elif x >= 4:
        print(x, 'th')
```

This is the output(sample):

```
Amount of numbers:8
1st
2nd
3rd
4 th
5 th
6 th
7 th
8 th
```

As you can see, all numbers after 4 have a whitespace between it and 'th'. How do I fix this?

Comment: use this for elif part `elif x >= 4: x = str(x)+'th' print(x)`

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print): *"`print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)`
Print `objects` to the text stream `file`, __separated by `sep`__ and followed by `end`."*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can [optionally give a separator argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) of whatever you want for "how comma should behave" (as another option to the other answers...

```
print("a","b",sep="+")
a+b
```

so you could just use `""`

```
print("a","b",sep="")
ab
```

if you do decide to use a single string as the other answers suggest you should really just use string formatting instead of `+` concatenation

```
print("{num}th".format(num=x))
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `,` comma, that automatically gives a space.

So change the last line from:

```
        print(x, 'th')
```

To:

```
        print(str(x) +'th')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the number to a string and then print it as

`print(str(x) + 'th')`

Or you can change the value of the default separator to an empty string rather than the default space:

`print(x, 'th', sep='')`

Answer (score 0):

#### Print function

You can convert the number to a string and then print it.
`print(str(x) + 'th')`

Or just use `sep`

```
num = input('Amount of numbers:')
num = int(num)
for x in range(1, num + 1):
    if x == 1:
        print('1st')
    elif x == 2:
        print('2nd')
    elif x == 3:
        print('3rd')
    elif x >= 4:
        print(x, 'th', sep="")
```

#### Using format strings

Or you can just use this though.

```
print("{num}th".format(num=x))
```

Or f strings

```
print(f"{x}th")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use fornatted string to plugin a variable in a string.
`f"{x}th"`